# Where is gnu lib math (libm) source code

Tags: gnu, libm

I want to download and compile the source code for libm (GNU's may library).

Can someone point me to the correct location / repository?

Answer (score 12):

It is contained in the C standard lib: [Glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc)

Comment: Just as a reference because one might land here when searching for it... the libm often used in embedded systems is part of newlib: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=tree;f=newlib/libm