# Where can I find the mathematical routines in GCC's source? How do the math functions work?

Tags: c, math, gcc, discrete-mathematics

Good night. I'm a Math bachelor and I'm studying log() and series. And I do want to see how GCC compute all those stuffs, it will help me a lot, there's nothing inside math.h I alread read it. I crazy trying to find how GCC compute logarithms and square roots using the fastest method ever. I donwloaded the source but I can't find where are the math routines.

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc

I just want to see it, I'm not a good programmer at all, my thing is math.

Comment: It's in the C library - see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550140/where-is-gnu-lib-math-libm-source-code

Comment: The GCC compiler itself uses libraries GMP, MFPR, MPC to do computation (amongst others).  The code generated by the compiler uses the C library (libraries) on your machine — often `-lm` to link the mathematics library, but sometimes that's not needed (e.g. on a Mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this log implementation](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_log.c).

This is from [fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/) that has the implementations (following the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)) of a lot of math functions in C for humans.

From the implementation:

#### Method

1. Argument Reduction: find `k` and `f` such that

```
    x = 2^k * (1+f),
    where sqrt(2)/2 < 1+f < sqrt(2) .
```

2. Approximation of log(1+f).

```
Let s = f/(2+f) ; based on log(1+f) = log(1+s) - log(1-s)
     = 2s + 2/3 s**3 + 2/5 s**5 + .....,
         = 2s + s*R
```

- We use a special Reme algorithm on `[0,0.1716]` to generate polynomial of degree 14 to approximate `R` The maximum error of this polynomial approximation is bounded by `2**-58.45`. In other words,

```
                 2      4      6      8      10      12      14
    R(z) ~ Lg1*s +Lg2*s +Lg3*s +Lg4*s +Lg5*s  +Lg6*s  +Lg7*s
    (the values of Lg1 to Lg7 are listed in the program)
```

and

```
    |      2          14          |     -58.45
    | Lg1*s +...+Lg7*s    -  R(z) | <= 2 
    |                             |
```

Note that `2s = f - s*f = f - hfsq + s*hfsq`, where `hfsq = f*f/2`. In order to guarantee error in log below `1ulp`, we compute log by

```
    log(1+f) = f - s*(f - R)    (if f is not too large)
    log(1+f) = f - (hfsq - s*(hfsq+R)). (better accuracy)
```

3. Finally,

```
     log(x) = k*ln2 + log(1+f).  
            = k*ln2_hi+(f-(hfsq-(s*(hfsq+R)+k*ln2_lo)))
```

- Here `ln2` is split into two floating point number:

```
        ln2_hi + ln2_lo,
```

where `n*ln2_hi` is always exact for `|n| < 2000`.

Real implementation and special cases of the explanation you can check in this [link](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_log.c).

Answer (score 6):

Mathematical functions are part of the C standard library, and GCC just uses those. If you want to look at the source code, you can either download the source code from the official [glibc website](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (for the GNU C Library version, which is one of the most used), or use [an online code browser](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/). Here's [the code for `log()`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log.c.html) for example.

Since you are saying you're not that much of a programmer though, I doubt you'll find the GNU C Standard Library comprehensible. It is the result of decades of optimizations and compatibility adjustments, and the code is very complex. **I would suggest to take a look at the [musl C Library](https://www.musl-libc.org/) instead**. The source code is much cleaner and more commented. [Here's the `log()` function](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/math/log.c), and here's [all the files regarding mathematical functions](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/math).

Finally, nor GCC or the C library have "the fastest method ever" to compute such functions. The goal of the C library is not to provide the fastest possible implementation of each mathematical function, but to provide a good enough implementation while still being portable enough to be used on multiple architectures, so those are still really fast, but most likely *not* "the fastest ever". In the best case, some mathematical function could even be reduced to a single CPU instruction if the CPU supports fast built-in hardware mathematical operations (like [for example Intel x86 with `fsqrt` for the square root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808940/x86-assembly-masm-square-root-of-a-64-bit-integer)).

Answer (score 1):

Functions like `log` are part of the math library that's commonly called "libm". Implementations of the standard C library, typically come with an implementation of libm, so what you are looking for is most likely in glibc. You can find the implementation of log in glibc here: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_log.c.html

There are some comments in the source code that give you hints about the algorithm used, but not a detailed explanation.

Of course there are different implementations of libm - for example there is [openlibm](https://openlibm.org/) and [netlib fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/). The documentation of both explain the algorithm used. Here is how `log` is implemented in openlibm: https://github.com/JuliaMath/openlibm/blob/master/src/e_log.c

<sub>(Interesting - looks like `log` in openlibm and fdlibm have come from the same source)</sub>