# Where are the header functions defined?

Tags: c

I'm learning CUDA and went to check how some functions worked a little more in depth because googling a specific structure variable gave me nothing. I used to think header files contained all the functions defined but all I saw was that they were declared.
I then went to to check if the pow() function in math.h was defined and was surprised to find out it also was never defined, just declared
Where can I see how these functions are defined?

Comment: You need to go find the source code for your system's C library.  It might be closed source, in which case you can't see it at all.  (C libraries can be precompiled, so you can use them even if the source is not available.)

Comment: You `#include <math.h>` and link with `-lm` which refers to the libm.so file.  The source for libm.so is not normally included but is available.  Have a look at: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/ 
  Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550140/where-is-gnu-lib-math-libm-source-code

Comment: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=math/s_cpow_template.c;h=71ce0c01126e6f9641a276a9dd4b9b17e1cc8454;hb=HEAD defines `pow(x,c)=exp(c*log(x));` and those two are defined in https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=math/s_cexp_template.c;h=bb6043155dbd5e0516878952fea87145d536dd64;hb=HEAD and https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=math/s_clog_template.c;h=3a723e9303a57d7a681029767fd3797ab18e6fca;hb=HEAD